# JavaScript not updating form action

Tags: javascript, php

I didn't attach the CSS as it doesn't matter for this question but for some reason my form won't submit I know you have to specify an action to do so which I do in the javascript but whenever I click on the button add to cart it just reloads this page [Products](http://ciswebs.smc.edu/CIS55/rowe_nalani_marissa/CongaMoe/products.php). Already tried the obvious put the addtoCart.php in the action but that causes other errors won't bring over the product id like I need it to. So is there any reason the javascript isn't updating my form action?

```
<body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">

<div id="container">
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="post"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="<?php echo session_id; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="cartNumber" value="<?php echo $cartNumber ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="productID" id="productID" value="">    
  <div id="header">
   <table width="760">
   <tr>
   <td width="188" rowspan="2">
    <a href="default.php"> <img  src="images/CongaMoe.jpg" width="150" height="153" alt="Conga Moe Logo" border="0"/></a>
    </td>
    <td width="361"><img src="images/homeTitle.jpg" width="343" height="152"></td>
    <td width="188">
     <a href="default.php"> <img  src="images/CongaMoe.jpg" width="150" height="153" alt="Conga Moe Logo" border="0"></a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="right">


    <a href="drums.php"><img src="images/btnCongaDrums.jpg" width="100" height="32" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="products.php"><img src="images/btnBuyAConga.jpg" width="100" height="32" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="viewcart.php"><img src="images/btnLookInCart.jpg" width="100" height="32" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="checkout.php"><img src="images/btnPayAndGo.jpg" width="100" height="32" border="0"></a> 
    </td><td width="3"></td>
  </table>
  </div>

  <!-- end #header -->

<div id="mainContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function addToCart(product, formObj) {
      document.getElementById("productID").value = product;
      document.getElementById("myform").action = "addtoCart.php";
      formObj.submit;
  }
  </script>
<table>
<?php
require_once('appVars.php');
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
   or die('Could not connect to MySQL server as CIS55Student, cis55 database.');
 $strQuote = chr(34);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM products_nalanirowe";
   $rs = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
   $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
      $productID = $row['productID'];
      $productName = $row['productName'];
      $productPrice = $row['productPrice'];
      echo "<tr class='productText'>";
      echo "<td valign='top'><input type='image' name='submit' src='images/btnAddToCart.jpg' width='100' height='32' border='0' onclick'javascript:addToCart(". $strQuote . "$productID" . $strQuote . ",this.form)' ></td>"; 
      echo "<td valign='top'>". $row['productID'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td valign='top'>". $row['productName'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td valign='top'". $row['productDesc'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td valign='top'>". $row['productPrice'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td valign='top'><img src='" . IMAGEPATH . $row['productImgName'] . "' border='0'></td>";
      echo "</tr>"; 
   }



  mysqli_close($dbc);

?>

</table>
<!-- end #mainContent --></div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p><strong>&copy;Conga Moes 2010</strong></p>
  <!-- end #footer --></div>
  </form>

<!-- end #container --></div>


</body>
```

Comment: Probably not related to the actual issue, but `form` should definitely not be a self-closing element

Comment: I'm curious to know if what you've setup is only a test and not something that is actually LIVE that people can buy online right now; not the way you've set this all up anyway. This in regards to security. Whether you'll be reading this or not is unknown, but if you do, remember this: if this is a LIVE site with the actual URL and method, is totally unsafe. Nothing to protect the user; no prepared statements, no SSL socket to pass payment into.

Comment: This is on a my school server it's not an actual site that'll be used to ecommerce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onclick'javascript:addToCart(". $strQuote . "$productID" . $strQuote . ",this.form)'` , you're not assigning  the handler properly and  this `formObj.submit;` should be `formObj.submit();`

Comment: feel like goofball now. I see what you mean didn't notice that till you pointed it out thanks. But yet it still reloads the product page even with that fix. So I'll continue to search for other missing issues

Comment: @NalaniRowe `return false;` from handler

Comment: Okay not sure what you mean by that

Answer (score 2):

the other error was

```
onclick'javascript:addToCart(". $strQuote . "$productID" . $strQuote . ",this.form)' ,
```

should read

```
onclick='javascript:addToCart(". $strQuote . "$productID" . $strQuote . ",this.form)' ,
```